# Is it possible to decorate function/method __get__ method?

Tags: python, function, get, descriptor

I'm trying to understand how methods are working as descriptors.

There is written something like: [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods):

*To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound methods when they are invoked from an object.*

Basing on this description and the fact that `"Dotted access from a class calls __get__()"` I assumed that it is possible to decorate `__get__` of class method.

I'm trying to wrap `someFunction.__get__`:

```
def wrap(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Wrapping...")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class SomeClass():
    def someFunction(self):
        print("someFunction called")
    someFunction.__get__ = wrap(someFunction.__get__)

obj = SomeClass()
obj.someFunction()
```

The output is just `"someFunction called"` as if nothing was not changed.

So my question is: why `Wrapping...` log is not printed?
Does the assignement:

```
someFunction.__get__ = wrap(someFunction.__get__)
```

anything?

Comment: I suspect that you have indeed wrapped the method, but are not invoking dunder get. What happens when you try obj.someFunction.__class__ for instance?

Answer (score 1):

From the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) documentation:

> The following methods only apply when an instance of the class containing the method (a so-called *descriptor* class) appears in an *owner* class (the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents).

I interpret that to mean that there's some kind of magic going on that requires `__get__` to be defined in the class (that of functions, in this case). It just won't work if you add it to an instance. I guess Python has to do some kind of initialization when a descriptor class is defined.

Comment: No, no initialization, it's just the way everything works